# DB connection in a non-public config.ini.php or as environment variable in apache2 server?

Tags: php, apache

I have a question about how to store my database config for my php web application in apache2 server. `(Apache/2.4.38 (Debian))`.

Should I store it in a non-public `config.ini.php` file or store it as environment variable in `/etc/apache2/envvars`?

Both looks good to me.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

honestly hard coding credentials in your source code is not a good security practice , so it's best to use apache envvars.

> IMPORTANT: If you have creds hard-coded in your files, refactor them
> out immediately. This is a bad security practice (and is mentions in
> both CWE-256 and the OWASP Top 10 (as A2) in the Broken
> Authentication item).

source: [keeping credentials secure in php](https://www.codementor.io/@ccornutt/keeping-credentials-secure-in-php-kvcbrk55z)